# ALias on an inner join intermediate result

Tags: mysql, sql, join

My SQL query fails when I assign an alias to the result of a join.

Here is the example:

```
SELECT 
    a, b, c 
FROM 
    ((q 
INNER JOIN 
    r ON q.x = r.y) AS IntermediateResult 
INNER JOIN 
    s ON IntermediateResult.a = s.a)
```

Basically the alias seems not to be recognized in the second inner join.

I am using Mysql

Comment: Mysql asks me to check my syntax around IntermediateResult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to label the results of an inner join as your intermediate result, because you can join directly to the table:

```
SELECT a,b,c FROM (
    SELECT * FROM q
    INNER JOIN r  AS IntermediateResult
            ON q.x=r.y
    INNER JOIN s
            ON IntermediateResult.a=s.a
) AS joined_qrs
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a subquery at all:

```
SELECT a, b, c
FROM q INNER JOIN
     r
     ON q.x = r.y INNER JOIN
     s
     ON q.a = s.a;  -- This is either q.a or r.a
```

The parentheses are also unnecessary, unless you are using MS Access.